# How to reference an object in an array of objects using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to output the referenceId of each subnet in a module that creates a virtual network with 4 subnets. I can get the first one, `[0]`, but when I try output the others, `[1], [2], [3]` the deployment fails and throws the error:

`The language expression property array index "1" is out of bounds`

Below is the code to create the virtualNetwork and the subnets:

```
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2018-11-01' = {
  name: vNetName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: subnets
  }
}
```

`subnets` is a variable of type array:

```
var subnets = [
  {
    name: mgmtSubnetName
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: mgmtSubnetAddressPrefix
    }
  }
  {
    name: intSubnetName
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: intSubnetAddressPrefix
    }
  }
  {
    name: extSubnetName
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: extSubnetAddressPrefix
    }
  }
  {
    name: vdmsSubnetName
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: vdmsSubnetAddressPrefix
    }
  }
]
```

When I use the output line below, it returns and array that has 4 objects...one for each subnet created:

`output subnets array = virtualNetwork.properties.subnets`

Each object has the format below:

```
{
    "name":"<value>",
    "id":"<value>",
    "etag":"<value>",
    "properties":{
        "provisioningState":"Succeeded",
        "addressPrefix":"<value>",
        "ipConfigurations":[
            {
                "id":"<value>"
            }
        ],
        "delegations":[]
    },
    "type":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
}
```

When I use the output line below, it returns the first object in the subnets array:

`output subnet1 object = virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[0]`

When I use the output line below, it returns the `resourceId` of the first subnet:

`output subnet1 string = virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[0].id`

I am unable to retrieve the other objects in the array using indexes `1, 2,` or `3`.

I have also tried the `resourceId` function (example below) but the behavior is exactly the same for indexes `1, 2,` or `3`:

`output subnet1Id string = resourceId('Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks/subnets', name, subnets[0].name)`

Comment: This is strange, both should work. Can you provide entire bicep file?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the below bicep template to ***deploy the vnet and subnets and output the subnets and subnet id's*** like below :

```
var subnets = [
  {
    name: 'vm-subnet'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix:'10.0.0.0/24'
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'webapp-subnet'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix:'10.0.1.0/24'
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'appgw-subnet'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix:'10.0.2.0/24'
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'bastion-subnet'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix:'10.0.3.0/24'
    }
  }
]
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2018-11-01' = {
  name: 'ansuman-vnet'
  location: 'east us'
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets: subnets
  }
}

output subnets array = [for (name, i) in subnets :{
  subnets : virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[i]
}]

output subnetids array = [for (name, i) in subnets :{
  subnets : virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[i].id
}]

output subnetappgw string = virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[2].id

output webappsubnet object = virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[1]
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I am using the latest Bicep version i.e. ***`Bicep CLI version 0.4.1124`***