# Trying to deploy naming convention in bicep and fails at the portal

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am going parameter file for each environment dev, prod, stg and calling respective parameter with the ps1 by changing the -templateparameter and the environment value.

I am passing index for env, approle and location from the parameter. Intellisense passes.

Eg for location in the main module passing locationShortName: locationList[locationIndex].locationShortname
Dev Parameter file

```
"locationIndex": { 
  "value":  1
}


 locationList": {
  "value": [
      {
          "Location": "westus2",
          "LocationShortName": "azw2"
      },
      {
      "Location": "eastus",
      "LocationShortName": "aze"
      },
      {
      "Location": "westus",
      "LocationShortName": "azw"
      },
      {
          "Location": "centralus",
      "LocationShortName": "azc"
      },
      {
          "Location": "westus3",
          "LocationShortName": "azw3"
      }
  ]
   }
```

I get -

The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds. Even though it should be picking up 'azw2'for 'westus2' shortname on index 1

Trying to call array and object value from parameter file to main module and pass it to submodule.

At the portal it shows - property array index '1' is out of bounds. Even though it should be picking up 'azw2'for 'westus2' shortname on index 1`your text`

Comment: well, can you share full code and full error text? or a repro

Answer (score 0):

> The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.

*This issue usually occurs when you try to access an index position or array element that is greater than the array element's length. Moreover, if you want to access* `locationshort azw2`, *you would pass array index as 0 because array length is taken from the* `0-index` *position.*

**I tried below output block to retrieve the array elements with the help of index values by adding a* `for loop`.*

```bash
output locationList array = [for (location, i) in locationList :{
  locationList : <ResourceName>.properties.locationList[i]
}]
```

After a workaround on this, I implemented a sample script for naming conventions in bicep by referring to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815460/how-to-reference-an-object-in-an-array-of-objects-using-bicep) by @Ansuman Bal and made a few changes and was deployed successfully.

```bash
resource exampleResource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2019-11-01' = {
  name: ResourceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    }
   locationList: locationList
  }
output locationList array = [for (location, i) in locationList :{
  locationList : <ResourceName>.properties.locationList[i]
}]
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was focusing on the index value for location where I had used idex = locationlist[locationindex) but it turned out to be envrionment array variable which only had first value but I was using 1 instead of 0

Comment: Instead of passing index for location, try using `for` loop to access all the array elements as I detailed in the above answer. @kpgkondo